# "Printing Not Allowed" in OSX app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to print a simple NSString value. But It gives me a dialog saying:

```
"Printing Now Allowed

This application is not allowed to print.

Please contact your application vendor for an update."
```

The code I use is:

```
-(void)printText:(NSString*)text
{
    NSTextView *printView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 468, 648)];
    [printView setString:text];
    [[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:printView] runOperation];
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is another symptom of this problem: When the user tries to print (as of 10.9.4 anyhow), the console will unhelpfully log: `Could not find image named 'GenericPostscriptPrinter'.`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found the answer!

I needed to check "Allow printing" under Entitlements under Summary under my target in project settings.

Comment: Found in Target/Signing & Capabilites/App Sandbox, Printing checkbox

Answer (score 9):

Go to Capabilities and to app Sandbox and then find under Hardware the checkmark for "PRINTING"

[image: PRINTING]

Answer (score 4):

Go to Your Project ---> YourProject.entitlements
Add the following Key-Value

> com.apple.security.print - YES

For [more info](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html)